# How does the Hubbard-Stratonovich (HS) transformation decouple interactions?

Tags: electrostatics, field-theory, interactions, classical-field-theory

I'm having trouble understanding how the Hubbard-Stratonovich (HS) transformation decouples equations via the introduction of a field variable. The particular problem I'm facing is a derivation in Phys Rev E, 81, 021501 (2010) equations 2.4 -> 2.7, where the author suggests that

$$ e^\left( -\beta H\right) = e^\left(-\beta\frac{e^2}{2}\int dr\;dr'\;\rho(r)C(r-r')\rho(r')\right) = \int D\phi\; e^\left(-\beta\int dr\; \frac{1}{2}\epsilon (\nabla\phi)^2 + i\rho e \phi\right) $$

Here, $C(r-r')$ is named the "Coulomb" operator, but is defined as the Greens function of the Poisson equation:

$$ \nabla\cdot[\epsilon \nabla C(r-r')] = \delta(r-r')$$

The other terms are what you'd expect: $\rho$ is a charge density, $\epsilon(r)$ is a dielectric function, $e$ is elementary charge and $\beta$ is $\frac{1}{kT}$.

**My stupid question:**

Apparently I'm bad at math and simply can't complete the square in the right hand side to get the left hand side. How... do you do this?

**My (hopefully) interesting question:**

What does it mean, conceptually, to decouple an interaction by introducing a field? I interpret the left hand side of the equation above as "$\rho(r)$ communicates with $\rho(r')$ through the $C(r-r')$ propagator" -- does this new field somehow contain all of this 'communication' information? Can I express the field $\phi$ in terms of $C$?

Comment: [Gaussian integral with linear term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_with_linear_term)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you would have found some answers by now..

For your first question, doing integrating by parts on $(\nabla \phi)^2$, you can change it to $\phi \Delta \phi$ right? then you can complete the square as usual.
You will have something like $(\phi + A\rho) M (\phi + A\rho) + B\rho M^{-1} \rho$ with A,B some coefficients and $M = \Delta$ (you might want to do it in momentum space)

For your second question, $C(r - r')$ in the left-hand side of your first equation will be the reciprocal of M which means it is a propagator. (Greens function)